# Make shell-command / async-shell-command respect carriage return?

Tags: process, shell-command

Say I have a simple perl program:

```perl
for my $i (0..10) {
    print "$i\r"
}

print "\n"
```

Now if I run the program through `shell-command`,
instead of getting a single line with `10`, I will see the following thing
in the output buffer.

```
  0^M1^M2^M3^M4^M5^M6^M7^M8^M9^M10^M
```

My question is how can I make the output look like the way similar to shell output (i.e. `\r` moves to the begin of a line, further output overwrites previous one, and `\n` switches to a newline).

Answer (score 1):

Emacs's echo area is not a regular interactive terminal that responds to \r; instead it collects all the output and presents it on one line. Anything sent to echo is also logged to the *Messages* buffer. Multi-line outputs to the echo area are instead displayed in a new buffer.

If you want to get just 10 as the response, then echo only the final result as follows:

```
for my $i (0..10) {
    $result=$i
}
print "$result"
```

On the other hand, if all output is needed with proper formatting, then replace \r with \n as shown here:

```
for my $i (0..10) {
    print "$i\n"
}
print "\n"
```

For more complex output with multibyte character output that is being mangled by the shell, you can tweak the

```
M-x universal-coding-system-argument
```

to specify command-specific encoding before running the shell-command. The shortcut for universal-coding-system-arugment is:

```
C-x RET c
```

Hope one of these helps.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is how can I make the output look like the way similar to shell output (i.e. `\r` moves to the begin of a line, further output overwrites previous one, and `\n` switches to a newline).

If you invoke the script via <kbd>M-&</kbd>(`async-shell-command`), then carriage returns are interpreted the way you desire by default. This behaviour is controlled by the variable `comint-inhibit-carriage-motion`:

```
comint-inhibit-carriage-motion is a variable defined in `comint.el'.
Its value is nil

Documentation:
If nil, Comint will interpret `carriage control' characters in output.
See `comint-carriage-motion' for details.
```

The reason asynchronous commands are displayed differently to synchronous ones is because the former receive `comint-output-filter` as their [process filter](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Filter-Functions.html), whereas output from the latter is not interpreted in the same way. If you think this should change, and someone hasn't already done so, you can submit a feature request via <kbd>M-x</kbd>`report-emacs-bug`<kbd>RET</kbd>.